# I want to find a struct from set with partial member of struct

Tags: c++, struct, stl

```
struct info{
            int a;
            int b;
            double c;
            double d;
            int e;
        };


set<info> infoSet;
info information;

information.a = 1;
information.b = 1;
information.c = 1;
information.d = 1;
information.e = 1; 

infoSet.insert(information);

information.a = 2;
information.b = 2;
information.c = 2;
information.d = 2;
information.e = 2; 

infoSet.insert(information);

typedef pair<int, int> pairs;
pairs p;
p.first = 1; p.second = 1;

set<info>::iterator it;

it.find(??)
```

c,d and e are depend on a and b in info struct(kind of super key in DB).
I want to find iterator of set which has struct members a and b exactly same as p.first and second. and want to print it 
which code do I have to put into (??) ?

Comment: Where is your comparison operator for `info` that lets you store it in a `set`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

first way:

```
set<info> infoSet

for_each(infoSet.begin(),infoSet.end(),bind2nd(ptr_fun(compare), pairs);

//compare fun
void compare(info, pair<int, int>)
{ 
  .....   you can compare them here
}
```

for_each is just like "for(..)", so the second way is

```
set<info>::iterator it = infoSet.begin();
for(it; it!=infoSet.end(); it++)
{
  if(it.first == p.first)
 {
   ...// do what you want
   break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your struct in a `set`, you need to provide a compare predicate for it.

I suppose that you want to make your struct as simple as possible, so I make the predicate and a convert function outside of your struct.

Example as follows:

```
struct Info
{
    int a;
    int b;
    double c;
    double d;
    int e;
};

struct CompareInfo
{
    bool operator() (const Info& lhs, const Info& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.a < rhs.a) && (lhs.b < rhs.b); // you can define your own rule here
    }
};

typedef std::pair<int, int> Pairs;

Info MakeInfo(Pairs p) // convert from Pairs to Info
{
    Info i = {p.first, p.second, 0, 0, 0}; // not sure what are values of c, d, e
    return i;
}

std::set<Info, CompareInfo> infos;
Info info1 = {1,1,1,1,1};
infos.insert(info1);
Info info2 = {2,2,2,2,2};
infos.insert(info2);

Pairs p(1,1);
auto it = infos.find(MakeInfo(p));
if (it != infos.end())
{
    // you found it!
}
```